# How to type annotate the return value of a macro?

Tags: types, macros, rust

Please have a look at this slightly contrived example:

```
use std::io::{Read, Result};

macro_rules! read_u8 {
    ($r:expr) => {{
        let mut buf = [0; 1];
        $r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf[0])
    }};
}

fn t<R: Read>(r: &mut R) -> Result<u8> {
    let x = read_u8!(r)?;
    Ok(x)
}

fn main() {
    use std::io::Cursor;
    let mut x: Cursor<Vec<u8>> = Cursor::new(vec![1, 2, 3]);

    match t(&mut x) {
        _ => println!("Done"),
    }
}
```

If you try to [run this example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=53fb0e2a89acad3a4d4e6ebdf53243d9&version=stable&mode=debug), you get:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |     let x = read_u8!(r)?;
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
```

How do I annotate the macro or the call site to get it to figure out I want to return the `Result` that is in scope?

Comment: In this case doing `let x = (read_u8!(r) as Result<u8>)?;` works, but i have no idea if that's recommended.

Comment: [The fact it's in a macro doesn't seem related.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=537ee276a05983132521ad2789b4171b&version=stable&mode=debug)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can explicitly indicate the block's return type with an inner variable declaration:

```
macro_rules! read_u8 {
    ($r:expr) => {{
        let mut buf = [0u8; 1];
        $r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        let ret: Result<u8> = Ok(buf[0]);
        ret
    }};
}
```

Or by casting:

```
macro_rules! read_u8 {
    ($r:expr) => {{
        let mut buf = [0; 1];
        $r.read_exact(&mut buf)?;
        Ok(buf[0])
    } as Result<u8>};
}
```